# Проблема с импортом в Go

Tags: golang

В проекте следующая структура файлов

```
project
|
=== connection
|   |
|   === connection.go
|
=== player
|   |
|   === player.go
|
=== game
|   |
|   === game.go
|
=== main
    |
    === main.go
```

В файле game.go компилятор подсвечивает

```
import "project/player"
```

Следовательно,и скомпилировать не могу. Подскажите,пожалуйста,в чём ошибка?

Comment: У вас GOPATH или go.mod настроены?

Comment: @Ainar-G go.mod? 0_o

Comment: Да. [Для определения корня вашего модуля и его зависимостей.](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Modules__module_versions__and_more)

Comment: Если IDE что-то подсвечивает, значит должно выводить какую-то ошибку. Если GOPATH не настроен, значит надо указывать полный путь до пакета player